# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, jdbc

When I use java code to insert data to oracle,the following information appeared:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1200)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
```

The oracle release is 11g.

Comment: Is there anything in the alert of your database? At the same time you got this message on your application? If you have then edit your question to add the information.

Answer (score 1):

For errors like this you should involve oracle support. Unfortunately you do not mention what oracle release you are using. The error can be related to optimizer bind peeking. Depending on the oracle version different workarounds apply.

You have two ways to address this:

1. upgrade to 11.2
2. set oracle parameter _optim_peek_user_binds = false

Of course underscore parameters should only be set if advised by oracle support